# Proving a subset of $\mathbb R$ is $G_{\delta}$.

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

Using the Baire Category Theorem, I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $d(x) = \text{dist}(x, \mathbb Z)$ denote the distance from $x \in \mathbb R$ to the nearest integer. For $q \in \mathbb Z_{+}$, $\alpha > 0$, define the sets
\begin{align}
   U_\alpha (q)=\{x\in \mathbb R:d(qx)<q^{-\alpha}\}
  \end{align}
and
\begin{align}
   Y_\alpha=\{x\in \mathbb R:x\text{ belongs to infinitely many } U_{\alpha}(q)\}.
  \end{align}

1. $Y_\alpha$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R$.
2. $X=\bigcap_{\alpha>0} Y_\alpha$ is a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R$.

My first question would be what the set $U_\alpha (q)$ exactly represents. Regardless of what it really is, I have was able to prove that $U_\alpha (q)$ is open. With this in mind,
\begin{align}
x\in Y_{\alpha} \iff \exists q_n: x\in \bigcap_{n} U_\alpha (q_n) \quad \forall n.
\end{align}
But now I do not know how to prove that $Y_{\alpha}=\bigcap_{n} U_\alpha (q_n)$.

For part 2, I though of proving that $Y_{\alpha}$ is also dense, so that
\begin{align}
X=\bigcap_{\alpha>0} Y_{\alpha}=\bigcap_n Y_{1/n}\cup \bigcap_n Y_n
\end{align}
and by the Baire Category Theorem, $X$ is dense. However, I am unsure how to prove (or realize it is untrue) that $Y_{\alpha}$ is dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the description of $Y_\alpha$ by
$$
x\in Y_\alpha \text{ iff } \exists (q_n)_n\,:\, x\in\bigcap_nU_\alpha(q_n)
$$
the quantifier $\forall n$ is misplaced and superfluous as it is already implicit in the $\bigcap_n$.
Next the sequence $(q_n)_n$ depends on $x$, so you should not expect $Y_\alpha$ to be equal to an intersection that involves just one sequence.

You can also describe $Y_\alpha$ thus: $x\in Y_\alpha$ iff for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q\ge n$ and $x\in U_\alpha(q)$.
Then $O_n=\bigcup_{q\ge n}U_\alpha(q)$ is open and $Y_\alpha=\bigcap_nO_n$.

To prove $Y_\alpha$ is dense it suffices to show that each $O_n$ is dense (by the Baire Category Theorem).